# Semantic UI: how to cut down the Item's height

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I am using the Semantic UI.

and here is my HTML [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZYmk/)
:

```
<div class="ui items" id="test">
<div class="item">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="meta">two days ago</div>
        <div class="name">hello</div>
        <div class="extra">ten pages</div>
        <p class="description">I am a pythoner</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#test{
    height:100px;
}
```

But it seems that CSS does't work. I can't change the height.

where did these go wrong?

Comment: you missing a closing `div` of `test`

Comment: @Paulie_D [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZYmk/)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. It seems likely that there is CSS in the base 'theme' that causes the `.item` div to be quite tall. http://jsfiddle.net/6ZYmk/1/

Answer (score 0):

You SemanticUI.css contains some base theming which determines the height of the `.item` class.

```
.ui.items>.row>.item, .ui.items>.item {
display: block;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0;
width: 316px;
min-height: 375px; /* here */
margin: 0 .5em 2.5em;
padding: 0;
background-color: #FFF;
line-height: 1.2;
font-size: 1em;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
border-bottom: .2em solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
border-radius: .33em;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .2s ease;
transition: box-shadow .2s ease;
padding: .5em;
}
```

You will need to change or delete that property.